# how to place the window in custom location on Android?

Tags: java, android

how can i set the Location of the window on screen in android OS? I want to set the window on top left corner of the screen. how can I do this?

The basic problem is, i am using dialog theme for my activity. Then activity appears in the center of the screen. I want that to appear at the top left corner of the screen. how can i achieve this?

Comment: plz show ur code what u have tried? are you using PopupWindow?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your activity as theme dialog  then you can use the following Code

```
 @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();

    View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
    lp.gravity = Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
    lp.x = 10;
    lp.y = 10;
    lp.width = 300;
    lp.height = 300;
    getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, lp);
}
```

if you are using Alert Dialog and want to adjust setting then you can follow the following code snippet

```
 private CharSequence[] items = {"Set as Ringtone", "Set as Alarm"};
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {

            if(item == 0) {

            } else if(item == 1) {

            } else if(item == 2) {

            }
        }
    });

     AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
     dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
     WindowManager.LayoutParams wmlp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();

 wmlp.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT;
 wmlp.x = 100;   //x position
 wmlp.y = 100;   //y position

 dialog.show();
```

Comment: Hi i have posted a better approach. please take a look. I honestly accept that i landed with the better approach only after looking at your code. The gravity thing i got only after looking at ur code. Thank u so much.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your Answer. It helped me a lot. I got the hint about Gravity only after looking at your reply. until then i have just ignored Gravity.

So I suggest a better approach. The top most container where the views lay down is "Window". The DecorView is also a view which will be laid on Window. So there is a simple way to achieve my requirement. it is as follows

```
    @Override
    public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
        super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
        Window win=getWindow();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams para=win.getAttributes();
        para.gravity=Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.TOP;
        para.x=10;
        para.y=10;
        win.setAttributes(para);
    }
```

Any ways thanks for your reply. It is really helpful.